# NameError only when trying to add a record to `has_many: "through` one way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am able to add doctors to locations using `location.doctor_profiles << doctor_profile` however I am receiving the following error when trying to add locations to doctors `doctor_profile.locations << location`

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `doctor_profile' for #<Location>
```

The association seems to work fine except in this once instance of adding a location to a doctor_profile

```
class DoctorProfile
  has_many :doctor_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :doctor_locations

class DoctorLocation
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :location

class Location
  has_many :doctor_locations
  has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_locations
```

Comment: I think you just need location.doctor_profiles.first since it is a has_many_through.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked the rails ActiveRecord Associations Guide and your setup looks fine.

Have you added associated ids in the database?

Comment: yeh, I had a callback that was throwing the error, it was just difficult to see the stack trace. thanks!